# How to make CodeIgniter respect line breaks on message when sending an email

Tags: codeigniter

How can I make codeigniter to send an email while respecting the line breaks from the message field?

the form message - http://d.pr/Sae5

```
<?php echo form_open($this->uri->uri_string()); ?>
<table class="forms-table">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <label for="name">Name</label>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" id="name" name="name" value="<?php echo set_value('name'); ?>" />
        </td>
        <td>
            <?php echo form_error('name'); ?>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <label for="email">Email</label>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" id="email" name="email" value="<?php echo set_value('email'); ?>" />
        </td>
        <td>
            <?php echo form_error('email'); ?>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <label for="message">Message</label>
        </td>
        <td>
            <textarea name="message" id="message" cols="40" rows="6"><?php echo set_value('message'); ?></textarea>

        </td>
        <td>
            <?php echo form_error('message'); ?>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="3">
            <input type="submit" value="submit" />
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
<?php echo form_close(); ?>
```

When I get the email, I get "hi, i am awesome" all in one line.  I have the newline and crlf config set to "\r\n", charset is "utf-8", and i get the value of my message field using

```
$message = $this->input->post('message');

...

$this->email->message($message);
```

any thoughts?

Comment: Can we see your config array you pass to the email load?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

why not send the email has html ?

first you must prepare the message (I'm assuming that you're using POST)

```
$message = str_replace ("\r\n", "<br>", $this->input->post('message') );
```

or you can use the native php way to get `$_POST`

```
$message = str_replace ("\r\n", "<br>", $_POST['message'] );
```

What you've done, is to replace new lines with `<br>`

Then you just need to load the lib and set it correctly trough config, for example:

```
$this->load->library('email');

$config['mailtype'] = 'html';
$this->email->initialize($config);


$this->email->from('your@example.com', 'Your Name');
$this->email->to('someone@example.com');

$this->email->subject('Email Test');
$this->email->message( $message );

$this->email->send();
```

That's it! I hope this helps,

You can get more info on http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/email.html
Hopefully you'll take the time to read it!

---

Just to add, you can simplify this process using `nl2br` and simply [`->mailtype = 'html';`](https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/email.html). Like so:

```
$message = nl2br($this->input->post('message')); // https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/input.html

$this->load->library('email'); // use autoload.php to remove this line
$this->email->mailtype = 'html';
```

---

Also, if you want to create a config to use all the time, you can actually create a config file and CI will use it automatically, thus you never need to use `->initialize`. To do so, just follow these simple steps:

- in the directory of **application\config**, create a file named **email.php**
- Then you can simply write in your configuration in that file like so:

---

```
`$config['mailtype'] = 'html';`
```

---

Viola! You're done. It's just that simple! Now just call your email class and use as usual with no need to configure things like `mailtype`. You can see full list of `email config` options under the title [**`Email Preferences`** *here*](https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/email.html). Don't forget, you can use the [**application\config\autoload.php**](https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/autoloader.html) to load the `email` library automatically, thus removing this line `$this->load->library('email');` from your code.

Comment: This worked for me with a little change $message = str_replace ("\n", "<br>", $result('message') );

Comment: You can also replace those coule lijnes of `config` with just a simple `$this->email->mailtype = 'html';`, also dont forget about [`nl2br`](http://us2.php.net/nl2br)